# Jquery dialogs interfering between them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not a js guy. I have this two js functions.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 500
        });
        $("#button").on("click", function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
    });  
});

function editar(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../controllers/editarEvento_controller.php?idEvento="+id,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#editarEvento").html(data).dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 500
            }).dialog("open");
        }
    });
}
```

How HTML buttons and divs look like.

```
<input id="button" type="button" class="botonAnadir" value="+Añadir evento">
<input type='button' class='botonGris' onclick='editar(some id);' value='Editar'/>

<div id="dialog" title="Añadir un evento"> a form inside </div>

<div id="editarEvento" title="Editar evento"></div>
```

Once time I click on editarEvento I can't open dialog anymore and throws me :

> " Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method 'open'".

I guess it have to be the ready function, I have no idea, I am just taking functions from some places :/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use following syntax to while printing `php` variable's value in `HTML`:  `<?php echo $id; ?>`

```
<input type='button' class='botonGris' onclick='editar("<?php echo $id; ?>");' value='Editar'/>
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

You don't have to use both

- `$(document).ready(function () {`
- `$(function () {`

Both are same. You can use any one of them like:

```
$(function () {//or $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 500
    });
    $("#button").on("click", function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: That input is inside an php echo, I just edited to try to avoid misunderstanding, sorry.

I deleted the $(document).ready(function ()  but nothing changed.